# CURL is not providing any values

Tags: php

my below code of PHP is not working. I have created test user id & password which is shared in the code. The file is not having any value. But I see with this code it is edited every time when I execute this code.

```
<?php
$username = '8632465';
$password = 'basade41';
$loginUrl = 'https://cabinet.instaforex.com/partner/login';
//$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0';
$config['useragent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0';

//$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $config['useragent']);

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Set the post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user='.$username.'&pass='.$password);

//Handle cookies for the login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

//Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
//not to print out the results of its query.
//Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
//from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute the request (the login)
$store = curl_exec($ch);

//the login is now done and you can continue to get the
//protected content.

//set the URL to the protected file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://cabinet.instaforex.com/partner/aff_statistic');

//execute the request
$content = curl_exec($ch);

//save the data to disk

file_put_contents('c:/xampp/htdocs/upload/test.txt', $content);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code missing some settings. eg:CURLOPT_CAINFO... 
This is my https code

```
<?php

//The CA certificate path
$caDir = '....../GeoTrustGlobalCA.crt';

//cookie file path
$cookieDir = '......';

//URL
$url = 'https://www.zhihu.com/......';

$defaultOpt = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36",
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,     // enabled SSL Cert checks
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_CAINFO         => $caDir,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     => $cookieDir,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      => $cookieDir,
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPGET        => true      //method is GET
);

$handle = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($handle,$arrOpt);

$content = curl_exec($handle);
$err     = curl_errno($handle);
$errmsg  = curl_error($handle);
$header  = curl_getinfo($handle);

curl_close($handle);

printf("Content is %s", $content);

?>
```

you can refer to this article [php-curl-https](http://sgq.me/2016/01/26/php-curl-https/) (in  (*^__^*)) OR this [using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/)

Comment: In your code I am getting  error. Can you please help me to add your code in to mine

Comment: I found api for the site that I can use. Currently it is returning value as [1481367,7546218]  . I want to insert this value in the database. So these are 2 values how can I update it in same column column 1481367 is different & 7546218. Also I don't want to insert the value if I have already inserted it before

Comment: I don‘t know weather I misunderstood it : you want to store [1481367,7546218] in two rows. If it correct, you can set the column as index or primary key, and then use sql like  these: `INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;` in the sql, column a is the primary key,if the row a=1 not exist, we will insert it,otherwise we will update c=c+1

Comment: API is returning value as [1481367,7546218]   I have not done echo any where but still it showing me this value. How can I do that.  I want to use this value in array brackets. For this I need to remove ][           . So there are two issues. firs tis not two show value as I am not doiing echo & second is I want to remove [] and take only value to next code for array.  I am done with duplicate value handling

Comment: 1. If you used my code, `printf()` will show the result. 2. you can just like  `$a = '[1481367,7546218]';` `$a = explode(',',trim($a,'[]')));`  to change string to array